# Returning a table from a stored proceudre (MS SQL) executed from Matlab

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, matlab

I have constructed a SQL query in MS Management studio which I would like to execute from Matlab. The query works perfect in MS Management studio but for some reason this query does not seem to work properly in Matlab so I have decided to create a stored procedure on the server, with one input parameter, which I then can execute from Matlab and receive the output (just a table view) back to matlab. Unfortunately this causes problems.

First of all - I do have a functional connection (conn) which I have tested various table extractions successfully. However, when trying to call my stored procedure I get an unexpected results.

When executing the following:

`x = exec(conn,'{call del.getVal(''123'')}')`

I receive the following:

```
    Attributes: []
          Data: 0
DatabaseObject: [1x1 database]
      RowLimit: 0
      SQLQuery: '{call del.getVal('123')}'
       Message: []
          Type: 'Database Cursor Object'
     ResultSet: [1x1 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet]
        Cursor: [1x1 com.mathworks.toolbox.database.sqlExec]
     Statement: [1x1 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement]
         Fetch: 0
```

For some reason there appears to be no data in this call. If executing this stored procedure from MS Management Studio I get the table view I want. So, **how would I be able to actually extract the table view which this stored procedure generates?**

System:

MS SQL 2008

Matlab 2014

Thanks

Comment: OFF TOPIC: The reason I think the query does not work directly from Matlab is because it joins multiple tables across database instances. Hence the argument for creating a Stored Procedure.